# dynamic buttons created in 2nd activity duplicate itself when press back then back to 2nd activity again

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, button

I am new to android. My dynamic buttons keep duplicating itself whenever I pressed the back button to go to the main activity then go back to the 2nd activity again.

Here are my codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void food_btn_handler(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FoodActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

---

//2nd Activity

[image: enter link description here]

```
public class FoodActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        loadFoodStatic();
        createButtonsForFoods();
    }
}

public class FoodActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        loadFoodStatic();
        createButtonsForFoods();
    }

    private void createButtonsForFoods() {
        ArrayList<Food> foods = Food.getFoods();
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_food);
        for (final Food f : foods) {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setText(f.getTitle());
            layout.addView(b);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(FoodActivity.this, DetailedActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("rid", f.getResid());
                    intent.putExtra("title", f.getTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("desc", f.getDescription());
                    intent.putExtra("moreinfo", f.getMoreinfo_url());
                    intent.putExtra("lat", f.getLatitude());
                    intent.putExtra("lng", f.getLongitude());
                    intent.putExtra("mark", f.getMarker());
                    intent.putExtra("temp", f.getTemperature());
                    intent.putExtra("cond", f.getCondition());
                    intent.putExtra("weather", f.getWeather_url());
                    startActivity(intent);  //start activity
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void loadFoodStatic() {

        Food.getFoods().add(new Food(R.drawable.pic1, "Food Title1","Food     Description1","http://www.food1.com",-34.0,151.0,"Marker1",11.1,"Text1",     "http://www.weather1.com"));
        Food.getFoods().add(new Food(R.drawable.pic2, "Food Title2", "Food     Description2","http://www.food2.com",2.222222,222.222222,"Marker2",22.2,"Text2",     "http://www.weather2.com"));
        Food.getFoods().add(new Food(R.drawable.pic3, "Food Title3", "Food     Description3","http://www.food3.com",3.333333,333.333333,"Marker3",33.3,"Text3",     "http://www.weather3.com"));
        Food.getFoods().add(new Food(R.drawable.pic4, "Food Title4", "Food     Description4","http://www.food4.com",4.444444,444.444444,"Marker4",44.4,"Text4",     "http://www.weather4.com"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you add Foods every time by calling loadFoodStatic. As the ArrayList/Foods is static/singleton it's kept between calls and each time the 2nd activity is created four more foods of the same type are added each time.

A simple way of getting fixit is to add a check for empty list first in your `loadFoodStatic`:

```
if (Foods.getFoods().isEmpty)  {
    ... //add foods here only
}
```

Comment: Great to hear @DanielA. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer ;-)